Can Eclipse be configured to convert a String to a text block if you hit enter while typing the string?
There are two things I'd like to figure out:

If I am typing a String literal and hit enter, it should be converted to a text block.
The same way you can highlight a block of text and hit CTRL+SHIFT+C to convert it to a multiline comment, there should be a key sequence for converting a highlighted block of concatenated String into a text block.

For example, highlight this:
String sql =
  "SELECT S.STOCK_ID, S.NAME, C.COLOR, S.PROD_DESCRIP, S.PRICE, S.PROD_FAM_ID " +
  "FROM STOCK S " +
  "INNER JOIN FAMILY F " +
  "ON S.STOCK_ID = ? AND F.PART_NUM = 'FINISH' AND F.FAMILY_ID = S.PROD_FAM_ID AND S.IS_ACTIVE = 1 " +
  "LEFT OUTER JOIN COLOR C ON C.COLOR_ID = S.COLOR " +
  "ORDER BY S.PRODNO,S.NAME";

And then CTRL+SHIFT+something to get:
String sql = """
  SELECT S.STOCK_ID, S.NAME, C.COLOR, S.PROD_DESCRIP, S.PRICE, S.PROD_FAM_ID  
  FROM STOCK S 
  INNER JOIN FAMILY F 
  ON S.STOCK_ID = ? AND F.PART_NUM = 'FINISH' AND F.FAMILY_ID = S.PROD_FAM_ID AND S.IS_ACTIVE = 1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COLOR C ON C.COLOR_ID = S.COLOR 
  ORDER BY S.PRODNO,S.NAME
  """;


A text block can be created by just using the Ctrl + Shift + ' shortcut; then start typing inside.
Note: text block support was added as Java 14 feature preview in Eclipse 2020-06
It seems there's no direct shortcut to convert to a text block (yet).
It could be done in 2 steps:

Select the text not including the ending semicolon. Hit Ctrl + Shift + '
or select Source > Add text block
Result:

private static final String sql =
     """
     "SELECT S.STOCK_ID, S.NAME, C.COLOR, S.PROD_DESCRIP, S.PRICE, S.PROD_FAM_ID " +
     "FROM STOCK S " +
     "INNER JOIN FAMILY F " +
     "ON S.STOCK_ID = ? AND F.PART_NUM = 'FINISH' AND F.FAMILY_ID = S.PROD_FAM_ID AND S.IS_ACTIVE = 1 " +
     "LEFT OUTER JOIN COLOR C ON C.COLOR_ID = S.COLOR " +
     "ORDER BY S.PRODNO,S.NAME"
     """;


Select the text again not including the triple quotes.
Hit Ctrl + F, check Regular Expressions and use
^(\s*)"([^"]+)"(\s*[;+]?) as the find expression and
$1$2 as the replace expression.
Hit Replace all
Result


private static final String sql =
      """
      SELECT S.STOCK_ID, S.NAME, C.COLOR, S.PROD_DESCRIP, S.PRICE, S.PROD_FAM_ID 
      FROM STOCK S 
      INNER JOIN FAMILY F 
      ON S.STOCK_ID = ? AND F.PART_NUM = 'FINISH' AND F.FAMILY_ID = S.PROD_FAM_ID AND S.IS_ACTIVE = 1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN COLOR C ON C.COLOR_ID = S.COLOR 
      ORDER BY S.PRODNO,S.NAME""";

The Find/Replace dialog may remained opened to perform more refactorings.

